# Export specific CSV filename (eg: abc*.csv) from list of folders within a folder using python through looping method

Tags: python, csv

How to iterate through multiple folders within a folder and export specific  CSV filename that begins for example-  "abc*.csv" and export them into a new folder directory.

Trying to search similar example in Stack overflow but most examples were reading multiple CSV files within a folder and combine them to one data frame. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any code to share?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Iterating through folders? Getting .csv filenames in those folders? Checking if they meet the pattern you need? Exporting them to somewhere else?

Comment: You’re not finding the solution because this is about searching files in folders and nothing to do with CSV except that is a filter for the file type you’re looking for in the folder(s).

Comment: Also since you’re dealing with files you will be copying them to a new location if they meet your find criteria…

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

files = []
source_dir = ['./files/']
dest_dir = './export/'

# List all files from all directories within the path
while len(source_dir) > 0:
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(source_dir.pop()):
        source_dir.extend(dirnames)
        files.extend(map(lambda n: os.path.join(
            *n), zip([dirpath] * len(filenames), filenames)))

# Loop thru files to copy/move the matching CSVs
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('abc') and file.endswith('.csv'):
        shutil.copy(file, dest_dir)
        # shutil.move(file, dest_dir)  # Use .move to move the file instead
```

If you have this file structure:

```
files
├── dir1
│   ├── abc789.csv
│   └── abc789.txt
├── dir2
│   ├── abc098.csv
│   └── abc098.txt
└── dir3
    ├── abc456.csv
    └── subdir3
        ├── abc123.csv
        └── abc123.txt
```

Only the matching files will be exported:

```
$ ls export/
abc098.csv abc123.csv abc456.csv abc789.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Sir  ! Yes the problem is described correctly.  However, when  i  ran the above code  i got  this error "str' object has no attribute 'pop' " . Please help. thanks.

Comment: you need to define the source as a list like `source_dir = ['./files/']` not a string because the sub-directories get added to that list

Comment: yes, i have defined them my source and new directory, yet the error "str' object has no attribute 'pop'  is shown . thanks

Comment: @JimmyWong again, if it says `"str' object has no attribute 'pop'` it means that you are setting the source dir as `source_dir = './files/'` instead of `source_dir = ['./files/'] `